# trying to find ijk values for 3d mesh plot

Tags: mesh, csv

i created a mesh monkey object from blender option. On the screen, you see the spreadsheet which only give xyz values and i trying to figure where are the ijk. The reason i want these values is to make a 3d mesh in plotly .[image]

On the second screenshot, I've exported the spreadsheet to be use in plotly studio and you see how the monkey look like with just the XYZ values which does not look right in plotly studio because it's missing the ijk values.[image]

I was wondering if blenders have the option to view/export ijk data so that the model would look like the same as in plotly studio?https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8960/what-are-the-i-j-k-components-of-a-3d-mesh-on-plot-ly-online

Answer (score 2):

Get *indices of mesh*

1. Go to *Edit mode*, select All and make *Triangulate Faces*

[image]

2. Exit *Edit mode* >To *Object mode*
3. Run script

[image]

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data

print("coor: ")
for vert in mesh.vertices:
    xyz = vert.co.xyz
    print(f"{xyz[0]}, {xyz[1]}, {xyz[2]}")
print("")

print("indices: ")
for face in mesh.polygons:
    print(f"{face.vertices[0]}, {face.vertices[1]}, {face.vertices[2]}")
print("")
```

4. Open console

[image]

[image]

### Export to csv

```
import bpy

outputFile = 'C:/yourlocation/list.csv'

obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data

coor = []
for vert in mesh.vertices:
    xyz = vert.co.xyz
    coor.append(f"{xyz[0]},{xyz[1]},{xyz[2]}")

indices = []
for face in mesh.polygons:
    indices.append(f"{face.vertices[0]},{face.vertices[1]},{face.vertices[2]}")

line = ["X,Y,Z,I,J,K\n"]
if len(indices) >= len(coor):
    for i, s in enumerate(coor):
        line.append(f"{s},{indices[i]}\n")
    for i in range(len(coor), len(indices)):
        line.append(f",,,{indices[i]}\n")
else:
    for i, s in enumerate(indices):
        line.append(f"{coor[i]},{s}\n")
    for i in range(len(indices), len(coor)):
        line.append(f"{coor[i]}\n")

f = open(outputFile, 'w')
f.writelines(line)
f.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Really impressive stuff. Do you if there is a possible way to export the indices values to a csv file?

The only way i manage to do it is to copy and paste the command prompt onto spreadsheet and use data - text to columns, delimiter command - finish. This will separate each value into a separate column.

Comment: Yes, it can. A write a new script for you.